# how to passing data from jquery with method POST into laravel controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, request

i had a problem when passing data from jquery ajax with method post to controller. i can't delete the product_tool table. it gives me callback error in ajax. not callback success.

and THERE IS NO ERROR in the console, but it give me error callback which is means there is an error. also when i debugging and look at the network (on firefox) the status is 500.

sory i'm late to edit it.

i have try every single solution on stack overflow. and nothing works.

here's my ajax script :

```
var token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
$.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '{{ url("/deleteProductTool/$cari->id") }}',               
                data: {
                    id_tool : id,
                    _token : token
                 },
                success: function(){
                    $.get('{{ url("/showTools/$cari->id") }}'), function(data, status){
                    $('#tool').html(data);
                }
                },
                error : function(response){
                    alert(response+" Gagal");
                }
            });
```

here's my route :

```
Route::post('/deleteProductTool/{id}','ProductController@deleteProductTool');
```

here's my controller :

```
public function deleteProductTool(Request $request, $id){
        if (Request::ajax()) {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        if (empty($product)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $tool = Tool::findOrFail($request->id_tool);
        if (empty($tool)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $hapus = ProductTool::where([
            ['product_id', $product->id],
            ['tool_id', $tool->id],
        ])->delete();

        // return $hapus;   
        }else{
            abort(404);
        }

    }
```

Comment: use `console.log(response);` instead of `alert(response+" Gagal");`

Comment: $hapus = ProductTool::where([
            ['product_id', $product],
            ['tool_id', $tool],
        ])->delete(); | Here you;re passing an object to the query, but the query need the ids to work properly.

Comment: i have fixed the query, but still it give me error callback in ajax :((

Comment: do i need a `dataType` in ajax ?

Comment: @FajarAlamRahmatSidik Plz update your question, this section `['product_id', $product->id],
            ['tool_id', $tool->id_tool],`

Comment: @FajarAlamRahmatSidik Plz show me ajax error

Comment: @Immeyti i have edit it. pls help me :'

Answer (score 0):

The alert in javascript does not know how to parse the object, try to print out the response in the console instead if you want to inspect it, so change this:

```
alert(response+" Gagal");
```

With

```
console.log(response);
```

And open the Console in your browser.

Comment: thx for your response. but that's not the problem. i mean the alert is not the problem. the alert is just for debugging.

Comment: You said in your question: "it give me alert like this : [object][object] gagal" so can you open the network tab and inspect what is going on with your request then? Because you are passing the data correctly as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in deleting **hapus**. Your **product** and **tool** are variables holding collection. Try like:

```
$hapus = ProductTool::where([
            ['product_id', $product->id],
            ['tool_id', $tool->id_tool],
        ])->delete();
```

Comment: thx for the response... oh yeah, i forgot..
but still, it's not work. still error callback in ajax :((

Answer (score 0):

You missed _token Field in Ajax data,
use as

```
var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{{ url("/deleteProductTool/$cari->id") }}',               
        data: {
            id_tool : id,
            _token:token
         },
        success: function(){
            $.get('{{ url("/showTools/$cari->id") }}'), function(data, status){
            $('#tool').html(data);
        }
        },
        error : function(response){
            alert(response+" Gagal");
        }
    });
```